# Why don't my transitions work on Bootstrap containers?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

I am trying to make a smooth bootstrap container transition, between container and container-fluid and vice versa. The transition works correctly on columns but not on container.

Below is an example of my code, in which the transition works only on columns, and does not work on container.
What is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .animation {
            flex-grow: 1;
            /*transition: all 400ms ease;*/

            -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
            -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
            -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
            transition: all 400ms ease;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="animation container px-5 py-5" id="main" style="background: green;">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="col1" class="animation col-md-8" style="background: red;">col1</div>
        <div id="col2" class="animation col-md-4" style="background: blue;">col2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="changecontainers()">change containers</button>
<button onclick="changecolumns()">change columns</button>

<script>

    var containerv = 1;
    var columns = 1;

    var container = document.getElementById("main");
    var col1 = document.getElementById("col1");
    var col2 = document.getElementById("col2");


    function changecontainers()
    {
        if (containerv)
        {
            container.classList.remove('container');
            container.classList.add("container-fluid");

            containerv = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            container.classList.remove('container-fluid');
            container.classList.add("container");

            containerv = 1;
        }
    }

    function changecolumns()
    {
        if (columns)
        {
            col1.classList.remove('col-md-8');
            col1.classList.add("col-md-4");

            col2.classList.remove('col-md-4');
            col2.classList.add("col-md-8");

            columns = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            col1.classList.remove('col-md-4');
            col1.classList.add("col-md-8");

            col2.classList.add("col-md-4");
            col2.classList.remove('col-md-8');

            columns = 1;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is there: https://jsfiddle.net/9r7e25mm/

Answer (score 3):

This is because to set the width of the element, `container` class uses a property `max-width` and `container-fluid` uses `width`. It's not possible to animate transition between two different properties. As a workaround you could create additional class `container-full-width` which sets `max-width: 100% !important` and add it instead of (or in addition to) `container-fluid`.

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle, the page is an `iframe`. Since its size is small, use cols - `col-sm-*` rather than `col-md-*`. If you copy the code with `md` columns and load as a seperate file in your browser, it will work. If the size specified by the class is greater than the viewport, the columns will stack no mattter the viewport. You need a look into the [grid system in bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

> Grid columns should add up to twelve for a row. More than that, columns will stack no matter the viewport. (Source: W3Schools)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            .animation {
                flex-grow: 1;
                /*transition: all 400ms ease;*/

                -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
                -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
                -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
                transition: all 400ms ease;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="animation container px-5 py-5" id="main" style="background: green;">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="col1" class="animation col-sm-8" style="background: red;">col1</div>
            <div id="col2" class="animation col-sm-4" style="background: blue;">col2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="changecontainers()">change containers</button>
    <button onclick="changecolumns()">change columns</button>

    <script>

        var containerv = 1;
        var columns = 1;

        var container = document.getElementById("main");
        var col1 = document.getElementById("col1");
        var col2 = document.getElementById("col2");


        function changecontainers()
        {
            if (containerv)
            {
                container.classList.remove('container');
                container.classList.add("container-fluid");

                containerv = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                container.classList.remove('container-fluid');
                container.classList.add("container");

                containerv = 1;
            }
        }

        function changecolumns()
        {
            if (columns)
            {
                col1.classList.remove('col-sm-8');
                col1.classList.add("col-sm-4");

                col2.classList.remove('col-sm-4');
                col2.classList.add("col-sm-8");

                columns = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                col1.classList.remove('col-sm-4');
                col1.classList.add("col-sm-8");

                col2.classList.add("col-sm-4");
                col2.classList.remove('col-sm-8');

                columns = 1;
            }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: But my problem is not the grid system at all. col-md are just an example of a transition, I mean that the transition works correctly on the columns,  but it does not work on replacing container with container-fluid